# Does Okami HD on PC support smooth run/walk blending?

Tags: controllers, okami, okami-hd

Most games, when played with an analog controller stick, allow you to seamlessly walk or run at any speed you like.

When I tried a borrowed Switch Pro controller with Okami, I was startled to discover that I could only walk slowly or run at full speed, with no in-between. Instead, it had a sharp, jarring transition about halfway to the edge.

I don't know if this is from the game itself, the controller, or some quirk of the pipeline in between. I've also never played any version before this, so I don't know if it was a limitation of the original, as well.

Does Okami HD for PC support analog speed control with a capable controller?

Answer (score 2):

I later tried the game on PC with a PS4 controller, and it still has digital walk/run. Looks like the game just doesn't support it, on PC at least.